# Get Current Cloud Services

Tags: c#, azure-cloud-services

I develop an application, with c# on Windows Azure, which has 3 cloud services (admin, portal, services). How can i to have the name of the current cloud service used ?

Comment: Are you using the Azure API? What code have you got?

Comment: I haven't code for this for the moment. I look for to have the name of the cloud services where is the method that i called. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
 RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id
```

This should give you the name of the cloud service, project and role instance (As a concatenated string). You could extract your service from that - presuming that code has different names for each service / project.